# Can't install Orchard CMS using Web Platfor Installer 4.0 - failed signature

Tags: .net, orchardcms, web-platform-installer

Can't download Orchard CMS using Web Platform Installer 4.0.

**This product did not install successfuly: Donwloaded file failed signature verification and may have been tampered.**

**part of the Log file**

DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9777770
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Error downloading product file: 'System.Net.WebException: InternetOpenUrl returned 0x80072EE7: Unknown error 12007.
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.ThrowGetLastErrorException(String offendingFunction)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.OpenUrlAndFollowRedirects(Uri& uri, IntPtr& hInetFile)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String fileName, String& contentDispositionFileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductManager.DownloadFile(Uri url, String cacheFileLocation, DateTime productFileLastModified)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductManager.Load(Uri productFileUrl, Boolean filterByArchitectureAndOS, Boolean loadEnclosures, Boolean useCachedVersion, String cacheDirectory, Architecture architecture, Int32 majorOS, Int32 minorOS, Int32 majorSP, Int32 minorSP, Int32 osType)
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 6, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/webapplicationlist.xml
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Error downloading product file: 'System.Net.WebException: InternetOpenUrl returned 0x80072EE7: Unknown error 12007.
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.ThrowGetLastErrorException(String offendingFunction)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.OpenUrlAndFollowRedirects(Uri& uri, IntPtr& hInetFile)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String fileName, String& contentDispositionFileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductManager.DownloadFile(Uri url, String cacheFileLocation, DateTime productFileLastModified)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductManager.Load(Uri productFileUrl, Boolean filterByArchitectureAndOS, Boolean loadEnclosures, Boolean useCachedVersion, String cacheDirectory, Architecture architecture, Int32 majorOS, Int32 minorOS, Int32 majorSP, Int32 minorSP, Int32 osType)
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 6, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/mediaproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Error downloading product file: 'System.Net.WebException: InternetOpenUrl returned 0x80072EE7: Unknown error 12007.
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.ThrowGetLastErrorException(String offendingFunction)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.OpenUrlAndFollowRedirects(Uri& uri, IntPtr& hInetFile)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String fileName, String& contentDispositionFileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductManager.DownloadFile(Uri url, String cacheFileLocation, DateTime productFileLastModified)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductManager.Load(Uri productFileUrl, Boolean filterByArchitectureAndOS, Boolean loadEnclosures, Boolean useCachedVersion, String cacheDirectory, Architecture architecture, Int32 majorOS, Int32 minorOS, Int32 majorSP, Int32 minorSP, Int32 osType)
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 6, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/toolsproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Error downloading product file: 'System.Net.WebException: InternetOpenUrl returned 0x80072EE7: Unknown error 12007.
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.ThrowGetLastErrorException(String offendingFunction)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.OpenUrlAndFollowRedirects(Uri& uri, IntPtr& hInetFile)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String fileName, String& contentDispositionFileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductManager.DownloadFile(Uri url, String cacheFileLocation, DateTime productFileLastModified)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductManager.Load(Uri productFileUrl, Boolean filterByArchitectureAndOS, Boolean loadEnclosures, Boolean useCachedVersion, String cacheDirectory, Architecture architecture, Int32 majorOS, Int32 minorOS, Int32 majorSP, Int32 minorSP, Int32 osType)
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 6, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/enterpriseproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Error downloading product file: 'System.Net.WebException: InternetOpenUrl returned 0x80072EE7: Unknown error 12007.
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.ThrowGetLastErrorException(String offendingFunction)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.OpenUrlAndFollowRedirects(Uri& uri, IntPtr& hInetFile)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String fileName, String& contentDispositionFileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductManager.DownloadFile(Uri url, String cacheFileLocation, DateTime productFileLastModified)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductManager.Load(Uri productFileUrl, Boolean filterByArchitectureAndOS, Boolean loadEnclosures, Boolean useCachedVersion, String cacheDirectory, Architecture architecture, Int32 majorOS, Int32 minorOS, Int32 majorSP, Int32 minorSP, Int32 osType)
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 6, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Getting ratings file from http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Error getting ratings file: System.Net.WebException: InternetOpenUrl returned 0x80072EE7: Unknown error 12007.
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.ThrowGetLastErrorException(String offendingFunction)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.OpenUrlAndFollowRedirects(Uri& uri, IntPtr& hInetFile)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String fileName, String& contentDispositionFileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductServiceImpl.DownloadFile(Uri webLocation, String fileLocation)
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product Orchard CMS (OrchardCMS) to cart
DownloadManager Error: 0 : WebClient download error. Uri: http://silverlight.microsoft.com/Assets/vs-webpi.png, Error: System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'silverlight.microsoft.com'
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.UI.DownloadServiceImplementation.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String filePath)
DownloadManager Error: 0 : WebClient download error. Uri: http://www.microsoft.com/web/media/gallery/apps-screenshots/wa_vs_graphic.png, Error: System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.microsoft.com'
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.UI.DownloadServiceImplementation.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String filePath)
DownloadManager Error: 0 : WebClient download error. Uri: http://www.microsoft.com/web/media/gallery/apps-screenshots/webmatrix-stack-6-256.png, Error: System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.microsoft.com'
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.UI.DownloadServiceImplementation.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String filePath)
DownloadManager Error: 0 : WebClient download error. Uri: http://www.microsoft.com/web/media/gallery/apps-screenshots/sql-option-a.png, Error: System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.microsoft.com'
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.UI.DownloadServiceImplementation.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String filePath)
DownloadManager Error: 0 : WebClient download error. Uri: http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx?command=getimage&guid=1291b73e-3858-4f10-a4b1-d99ed02174e4, Error: System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.microsoft.com'
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.UI.DownloadServiceImplementation.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String filePath)
DownloadManager Error: 0 : WebClient download error. Uri: http://www.microsoft.com/web/media/gallery/apps-screenshots/Microsoft-App-Request-Routing.png, Error: System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.microsoft.com'
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.UI.DownloadServiceImplementation.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String filePath)
DownloadManager Error: 0 : WebClient download error. Uri: http://www.microsoft.com/web/media/gallery/apps-screenshots/IIS_WebPlatformInstaller_GenericWizardArt.png, Error: System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.microsoft.com'
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.UI.DownloadServiceImplementation.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String filePath)
DownloadManager Error: 0 : WebClient download error. Uri: http://www.microsoft.com/web/media/icons/vs-logo-sm.png, Error: System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.microsoft.com'
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.UI.DownloadServiceImplementation.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String filePath)
DownloadManager Error: 0 : WebClient download error: System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'go.microsoft.com'
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductServiceImpl.DownloadFile(Uri webLocation, String fileLocation)
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading ratings file from cache C:\Users\TITO\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\1055370499.xml
DownloadManager Error: 0 : WinInet download error. Uri: http://silverlight.microsoft.com/Assets/vs-webpi.png, Error: System.Net.WebException: InternetOpenUrl returned 0x80072EE7: Unknown error 12007.
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.ThrowGetLastErrorException(String offendingFunction)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.OpenUrlAndFollowRedirects(Uri& uri, IntPtr& hInetFile)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String fileName, String& contentDispositionFileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.UI.DownloadServiceImplementation.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String filePath)
DownloadManager Error: 0 : WinInet download error. Uri: http://www.microsoft.com/web/media/gallery/apps-screenshots/wa_vs_graphic.png, Error: System.Net.WebException: InternetOpenUrl returned 0x80072EE7: Unknown error 12007.
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.ThrowGetLastErrorException(String offendingFunction)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.OpenUrlAndFollowRedirects(Uri& uri, IntPtr& hInetFile)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String fileName, String& contentDispositionFileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.UI.DownloadServiceImplementation.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String filePath)
DownloadManager Error: 0 : WinInet download error. Uri: http://www.microsoft.com/web/media/gallery/apps-screenshots/webmatrix-stack-6-256.png, Error: System.Net.WebException: InternetOpenUrl returned 0x80072EE7: Unknown error 12007.
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.ThrowGetLastErrorException(String offendingFunction)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.OpenUrlAndFollowRedirects(Uri& uri, IntPtr& hInetFile)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String fileName, String& contentDispositionFileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.UI.DownloadServiceImplementation.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String filePath)
DownloadManager Error: 0 : WinInet download error. Uri: http://www.microsoft.com/web/media/gallery/apps-screenshots/sql-option-a.png, Error: System.Net.WebException: InternetOpenUrl returned 0x80072EE7: Unknown error 12007.
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.ThrowGetLastErrorException(String offendingFunction)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.OpenUrlAndFollowRedirects(Uri& uri, IntPtr& hInetFile)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String fileName, String& contentDispositionFileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.UI.DownloadServiceImplementation.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String filePath)
DownloadManager Error: 0 : WinInet download error. Uri: http://www.microsoft.com/web/media/gallery/apps-screenshots/Microsoft-App-Request-Routing.png, Error: System.Net.WebException: InternetOpenUrl returned 0x80072EE7: Unknown error 12007.
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.ThrowGetLastErrorException(String offendingFunction)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.OpenUrlAndFollowRedirects(Uri& uri, IntPtr& hInetFile)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String fileName, String& contentDispositionFileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.UI.DownloadServiceImplementation.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String filePath)
DownloadManager Error: 0 : WinInet download error. Uri: http://www.microsoft.com/web/media/gallery/apps-screenshots/IIS_WebPlatformInstaller_GenericWizardArt.png, Error: System.Net.WebException: InternetOpenUrl returned 0x80072EE7: Unknown error 12007.
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.ThrowGetLastErrorException(String offendingFunction)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.OpenUrlAndFollowRedirects(Uri& uri, IntPtr& hInetFile)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String fileName, String& contentDispositionFileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.UI.DownloadServiceImplementation.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String filePath)
DownloadManager Error: 0 : WinInet download error. Uri: http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx?command=getimage&guid=1291b73e-3858-4f10-a4b1-d99ed02174e4, Error: System.Net.WebException: InternetOpenUrl returned 0x80072EE7: Unknown error 12007.
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.ThrowGetLastErrorException(String offendingFunction)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.OpenUrlAndFollowRedirects(Uri& uri, IntPtr& hInetFile)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String fileName, String& contentDispositionFileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.UI.DownloadServiceImplementation.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String filePath)
DownloadManager Error: 0 : WinInet download error. Uri: http://www.microsoft.com/web/media/icons/vs-logo-sm.png, Error: System.Net.WebException: InternetOpenUrl returned 0x80072EE7: Unknown error 12007.
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.ThrowGetLastErrorException(String offendingFunction)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.OpenUrlAndFollowRedirects(Uri& uri, IntPtr& hInetFile)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String fileName, String& contentDispositionFileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.UI.DownloadServiceImplementation.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String filePath)
DownloadManager Error: 0 : WebClient download error. Uri: http://www.microsoft.com/web/media/gallery/apps-screenshots/webplatformsplashscreen.png, Error: System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.microsoft.com'
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.UI.DownloadServiceImplementation.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String filePath)
DownloadManager Error: 0 : WebClient download error. Uri: http://www.microsoft.com/web/media/gallery/apps-screenshots/webplatformsplashscreen.png, Error: System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.microsoft.com'
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.UI.DownloadServiceImplementation.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String filePath)
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product 'OrchardCMS'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'NETFramework4' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WindowsImagingComponent' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WebMatrix' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'SQLCE' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WindowsInstaller45' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'SQLCETools' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'Plan9' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'Plan9v1' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'Plan9v1Loc' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'SMO32' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'SQLNativeClient' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'SQLCLRTypes32' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WDeployNoSMO' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'netframework2' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WindowsInstaller31' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WDeploy_Installer' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'IISExpress' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Setting current install to 1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting install sequence
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http://orchard.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?DownloadId=288791' to: C:\Users\TITO\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpF762.tmp
DownloadManager Error: 0 : WinInet download error. Uri: http://www.microsoft.com/web/media/gallery/apps-screenshots/webplatformsplashscreen.png, Error: System.Net.WebException: InternetOpenUrl returned 0x80072EE7: Unknown error 12007.
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.ThrowGetLastErrorException(String offendingFunction)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.OpenUrlAndFollowRedirects(Uri& uri, IntPtr& hInetFile)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String fileName, String& contentDispositionFileName)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.UI.DownloadServiceImplementation.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String filePath)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clear your IE cache and try again.